# How to use/install raspberry pi camera on ubuntu os

Tags: pi-4, raspicam, ubuntu

I am wanting to use ubuntu v20.04 64 on my Raspberry Pi 4.
I also what to be able to use the on-board camera.

I have followed these steps to install and boot up my Rpi4 with Ubuntu:

```
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#2-prepare-the-sd-card
```

This is not really relevant to my question and is just a reference hence the link only.

From Googling I have used these steps to install the camera modules:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'start_x=1' >> /boot/config.txt"
sudo bash -c "echo 'gpu_mem=128' >> /boot/config.txt"

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt install cmake
cd /home
sudo git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland
cd userland
sudo ./buildme --aarch64
```

I then reboot and try to create an image using this command:

```
sudo raspistill -o cam.jpg
```

I get this error:

```
raspistill command not found.
```

What else can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues/630
support for MMAL is broken in 64bit arm64. Thus raspistill won't build and is not packaged for arm64.

Answer (score 0):

The config file config.txt is in /boot/firmware not in boot folder for ubuntu 20.04 LTS. if the line  start_x=1 is present in the file, there is no need to try to raspi-config or raspistill which is not supported in ubuntu 20.04. U can add the start_x=1 line in the config.txt file by $sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt

try installing cheese through terminal which will display the camera feed and also it will list all the cameras connected to the Rasberry pi 4

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **raspi-config** tool.

In a terminal type below command to install the tool.

```
sudo apt install raspi-config
```

Then open the tool using

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Once the tool screen is openwed, go to Interface Options and then enable "Legacy camera option".

More about raspi-config tool [Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html)